# Apply different class to table tr based on image title

Tags: jquery, xhtml

```
<table id='xhtmlgrid'>
<tbody>
<tr class='bgwhite'>
<td>
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<span>
<img src="./secured_off1.png">
</span>
</td>
<td>
<span>
<img src="./secured_off2.png">
</span>
</td>
<td>
<span>
<img src="./secured_off3.png" title="Locked">
</span>
</td>
<td>
<span>
<img src="./secured_off4.png">
</span>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

[image]

i have code like this,based on image title,i have multiple images in that tr, i want to change the tr class from bgwhite to bggreen,how can i do that,any help appreciated.

so far i'm using this code to find the image title

```
$("#xhtml_grid table > tbody > tr").each(function () {
        var hdnLock = $(this).find('td:eq(2)').find('img').attr('title');
        if (hdnLock == 'Locked') {
        }

    });
```

for reference i'm adding the image of html

Comment: By the way, your source is HTML rather than XHTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#xhtml_grid table > tbody > tr").each(function () {
        var hdnLock = $(this).find('td:eq(2)').find('img').attr('title');
        if (hdnLock == 'Locked') {
            $(this).parents('tr').css('background-Color', '#ddff99');
        }
    });
```

Thanks everyone for your support and suggestions, I found a way for my issue, here I'm posting my code that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is mostly correct. I had to change the table id in the first selector. And I removed the `td:eq(2)`. It wasn't correct. You can select image directly instead assuming there is only one image in the row.

```js
$("#xhtmlgrid tbody > tr").each(function () {
  var hdnLock = $(this).find('img').attr('title');
  if (hdnLock == 'Locked') {
    $(this).addClass('bggreen').removeClass('bgwhite');
  }
});
```

```css
.bgwhite {
  background: red;
}

.bggreen {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id='xhtmlgrid'>
  <tbody>
  <tr class='bgwhite'>
    <td>
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <img src="./secured_off.png" title="Locked">
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: i'm not trying to apply CSS class to closest tr, I'm trying to apply to the above tr

Comment: My code doesn't apply to closest tr, it applies it to the tr with class 'bgwhite'. *edit* Sorry, my bad. I've updated my code to be correct. The only change is that the first selector was: `#xhtmlgrid > table > tbody > tr` and now is: `#xhtmlgrid > tbody > tr`. That way we loop over the rows of the main table only.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of traversing through each `tr`, traverse through each `img`, that would improve the performance and reduce the unnecessary traversing. Below is the updated code:

```js
$("#xhtmlgrid table > tbody > tr > td > img").each(function() {
  if ($(this).attr('title') == 'Locked') {
    $(this).closest('tr').addClass('bggreen').removeClass('bgwhite');
  }
});
```

```css
.bgwhite {
  background: red;
}

.bggreen {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id='xhtmlgrid'>
  <tbody>
    <tr class='bgwhite'>
      <td>
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <img src="./secured_off.png" title="Locked">
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <img src="./secured_off.png" title="unlocked">
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: i'm not trying to apply CSS class to closest tr, I'm trying to apply to the above tr

Comment: Closest would apply to the above tr only. that's how closest works.

Comment: I have multiple images in that TD, that's why I'm using td:eq(2) to find out image with title='Locked'

Comment: In that case, based on your question, how will you assign a class to `tr`, it it has 3 `td` and only 1 `td` has image??? Your question is kinda incorrect.

Comment: my requirement is like that, that is why I'm here for help :) is there any chance that we can identify the same row with class name bgwhite and change the CSS??

Comment: We can identify in many ways, but before that, you need to clear the requirements and question. Are you adding class to `tr` or to `td`? If a row has 5 `td` but only 3 images, what happens to `tr`? Should class be added or not.. ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158932/discussion-between-bhanu-mankena-and-milan-chheda).

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to change those trs that start out with `class="bgwhite"`, what you need to do is traverse over those explicitly, and then check for each if there's at least one img with `title="Locked"` inside.

```js
var whiteTrs = document.querySelectorAll('#xhtmlgrid tr.bgwhite');
whiteTrs.forEach(function(tr) {
  if (tr.querySelector('img[title="Locked"]')!=null)
    tr.className = 'bggreen';
});
```

```css
.bgwhite {background:white}
.bggreen {background:green}
```

```html
<table id='xhtmlgrid'>
<tbody>
<tr class='bgwhite'>
<td>
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<span>
<img src="./secured_off1.png">
</span>
</td>
<td>
<span>
<img src="./secured_off2.png">
</span>
</td>
<td>
<span>
<img src="./secured_off3.png" title="Locked">
</span>
</td>
<td>
<span>
<img src="./secured_off4.png">
</span>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```